# MessageBoxButtons and MessageBoxIcon error

Tags: c#, messagebox

I'm trying to show a messagebox and I want to add an Error Icon to it but I'm taking this error message:

"2 arguments: Cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons' to 'string'."
How can I fix it? Thanks for your help.

```
else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect code or password", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); 
        }
```

Comment: The second parameter should be a string for the caption title. Then come the parameters for buttons and icons

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an overload with those parameters. You'll have to provide a title or `caption`

```
public static System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult Show (
    string text,
    string caption, 
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons buttons,
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon icon);
```

You can view [all overloads available here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show).